# How to enable curl in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, cpanel, php-curl

How to enable cURL on Wordpress.  I check my file manager there  are exist cURL.php on my server and I have also enabled in PHP.ini file(removed ; before extension) but still I'm getting error like cURL not enabled.

I install plugin too but its not working

Comment: Did you amend the correct copy of php.ini and restart the webserver afterwards? What is your operating system? How did you install the curl extension exactly?